# Delete of .class file

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Sometimes when I execute my java project on NetBeans 8.2, some .class file disappear and return NoDefFoundError.
 Why do this happens? 
I've tried to copy a backup file into "build" directory of the project. It works for some attempts, after it disappears again. 
it is not always in the same file, but often in files without main method.
How does it happen?

Comment: it must be because of "clean" target

Comment: The last time it happened, I was running a class who gave me a generic error (a null pointer) and I forced the stop. Fixed the error, I re-run the class netbeans made me ClassDefFoundError ... I checked the path of the file and actually missed the .class file, but I have no idea how it might have deleted it ...